# Does your app contain, display, or access third-party content?

Tags: ios, app-store

So as I'm submitting my iOS application a new question pops up from Apple that I've never seen before.

> Does your app contain, display, or access third-party content?

Yes it does, it contains **random images** of players from Google such as this: http://gyazo.com/6ed035ba3dd79bfba7fc5c5afce12354.png

I'm also HTML parsing matches from **FoxSports** as shown here: http://gyazo.com/4957af9a5326ee7d953eb621506d07ac.png

However if I tick *Yes*, it asks me another question:

> Do you have all necessary rights to that content or are you otherwise
>   permitted to use it under the laws of each App Store territory in
>   which your app is available (for example, fair use)?

Do I have those rights?

**EDIT:**

If I use this Google Image search and tick "Labeled for reuse" could I use the image and just give credit to the link ?

http://gyazo.com/bb472c1382357de3ad8d431ed95cf589.png

Comment: This is a general IP rights question, does not have anything to do with Apple

Comment: @HasAlTaiar that specific question "Does your app contain, display, or access third-party content?" is now asked by Apple during the app submission process.

Comment: Thanks @William Denniss, but as a general rule of thumb, you should have the right to publish any materials whether on Apple or anywhere else before thinking of releasing/pub ur app. And if so, then you just answer yes. Thanks

Comment: @HasAlTaiar indeed! And now Apple is asking us all to confirm that fact. This is a new change in iTunes connect (as recently as a week ago that question was not asked) so I expect a few people may find this question if they wondering _why_ Apple has started asking this question (as I was). Maybe they put it there simply as a reminder that we should all be well considering this matter.

Comment: Well said @William Denniss :)

Comment: Hmmm...wondering what Facebook would answer when submitting a new version :-) Fair-use probably.

Comment: Please check on my edit!

Comment: Google's support page on "labeled for reuse": https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/29508?hl=en

So, the short answer is: no. You can't automatically assume that you can legimately reuse all images returned by google image search, even if you're ticking the 'labeled for reuse' option.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about IP rights, not programming.

Answer (score 9):

Did the copyright owners of those images give you permission to use the images? If so, you have the rights. If not, you probably don't.

Contact an intellectual property lawyer if in doubt.

Comment: Please check on my edit.

Comment: In that case, see what Google say about that:

[https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/29508?hl=en]

**Make sure you read the text in red!**

Comment: Should i check box if i use google drive, Drop box to get image from user account?